# CodeIgniter Active Records where in subquery

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

How do I write where_in statement a subquery using codeigniter active records ?

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(a.transaction_payment_amount) FROM 
         transaction_payment a WHERE a.transaction_link IN 
         (SELECT transaction_link FROM transaction WHERE transaction_type = '22'");
$result = $query->result();
```

Now how to convert the above query into CI active records ?

I have tried:

```
$this->db->select("SUM(a.transaction_payment_amount)");
$this->db->from('transaction_payment a');
$this->db->where_in('a.transaction_link', "SELECT transaction_link from transaction WHERE transaction_type = '22'");
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: If it is possible, there is no benefit. It's no more portable than it was when you use the query method.

Comment: @BrianGottier Well my query is just an example, my actual code is way longer and more table and column that it becomes a little bit harder to read, with active records (if it does have the same speed), will be neater and easier to read.

Comment: If your query is way longer and more complex, it sounds like you just need to use formatting/indenting to make it easier to read.

Comment: @BrianGottier Well yeah of course, I still like active records more for some reason, just wondering if it's possible to do the query in active records.

Comment: @Brian the big advantage of the query builder is - you can easily split up the query in multiple functions in your model and still get your desired result - with a single query those benefits are inexistent beside the fact that you can make database independent applications...

Comment: @sintakonte, there is nothing about this query that could be database independent. One can not simply move a database to SQLite, PostgreSQL, etc. and think this query will still work. There's also ways to build SQL quite easily without using anything other than plain PHP, but I get what you mean, I just don't agree it's actually beneficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This

```
$this->db->where_in('a.transaction_link', "SELECT transaction_link from transaction WHERE transaction_type = '22'",false);
```

if you use false then it will remove single quotes from `where_in` condition

Comment: "false"!, damnit, exactly what i'm looking for, didn't know there is that argument. Thank you!

Comment: you can also use `false` in `select`,`from` like in every active record then it will remove `single quote` from active records. and Welcome

Answer (score 1):

Sharmas Answer should do the job but if you wish fully supported Query Builder Methods you can try this

```
$strSubQuery = $this->db
    ->select("transaction_link")
    ->from("transaction")
    ->where("transaction_type",22)
    ->get_compiled_select();

$query = $this->db
    ->select("SUM(a.transaction_payment_amount)", false)
    ->from('transaction_payment a')
    ->where_in('a.transaction_link', $strSubQuery, false)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code as following solution.

> Changes your query

```
$this->db->select("SUM(a.transaction_payment_amount)");
$this->db->from('transaction_payment a');
$this->db->where("a.transaction_link IN (SELECT transaction_link from transaction WHERE transaction_type = '22')", null, false);
//OR you can try other where condition if Sub query return null value than used this below query
$this->db->where("IF(SELECT transaction_link from transaction WHERE transaction_type = '22',a.transaction_link IN (SELECT transaction_link from transaction WHERE transaction_type = '22'), NULL)", null, false);
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result();
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!